# Android: Can a ListView Adapter use the context of its constructor for Toast?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-context

In the constructor of my `ArrayAdapter`, the second parameter is a `Context`:

`public MyAdapter(LayoutInflater layout_inflater, @NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<DocumentSnapshot> users) {`

In this class, I need to query a server using the value of an attribute of a given `DocumentSnapshot` (from the list `users`).

If this query fails, I want to show a `Toast` to the app user. Can I use the `Context` object of the constructor, as an object attribute of course, for this `Toast`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Answer your Question, of course you can, it's better to give the App Context when not in ui(activity/fragment) to avoid memory leak,

But you should review your implementation, Usually, Network queries are not in the Adapter, you could try to query before setting your Adapter